# how to get selected text of select2 and use it in a sql statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-select2

I am trying to get the selected text of the select2 element and use it in a custom sql statement which will return json and i will render the json to morris bar chart...can anyone assist me with what i need to do? below you will find the code i currently have. thanks in advance

DAL:

```
public DataTable GetBookingTrend()
        {
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            strBuilder.Append("select WEEKNO, YEARNO, SUM(NOOFWEEKS) from BOOKINGTREND where ( SCHOOLCOUNTRY in (select2.text)) group by weekno, yearno");
            DataTable dt;

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strBuilder.ToString(), connStr))
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
            return dt;
        }
```

SERVICE:

```
public List<BookingTrend> GetBookingTrendList()
    {
        List<BookingTrend> bookingtrends = new List<BookingTrend>();
        sqlDal dal = new sqlDal();

        foreach (DataRow item in dal.GetBookingTrend().Rows)
        {
            BookingTrend bookingtrend = new BookingTrend();
            bookingtrend.weekno = (int)item["WEEKNO"];
            bookingtrend.yearno = (int)item["YEARNO"];
            bookingtrends.Add(bookingtrend);
        }
        return bookingtrends;
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult BookingTrendRead()
    {
        Services.sqlService ss = new Services.sqlService();

        return Json(ss.GetBookingTrendList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Booking Trend
    </div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="booking-trend-bar" style="height: 250px"></div>
</div>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
     <select class ="form-control" id="SchoolDestinations" style="width:385px;" multiple>
          <option></option>
     </select>
</div>
```

DOCUMENT READY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 function createChart(data) {
        var mychart = new Morris.Bar({
            element: 'booking-trend-bar',
            data: data,
            xkey: 'Country',
            ykeys: ['weekno','yearno'],
            labels: ['Week', 'Year']
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("BookingTrendRead", "Main")',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);

            createChart(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
        }
    });

$("#SchoolDestinations").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        placeholder: "School Destinations"
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("SchoolRead", "Main")',
    dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $('<option value="' + item.Id + '">' + item.Text + '</option>').appendTo('#SchoolDestinations');
            });
        },
    error: function () {
        console.log('err')
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Does the form element's value not get posted with the form?  Or, if you're using that AJAX request, why aren't you sending any data with it?  Where does that server-side code get used at all?  It's not really clear what you're doing.

Comment: right now all i have is the ajax to render the select2 element, what i am trying to do is get the selected value and bind it to a sql statement..

Comment: But how does any of this code actually fit together?  What invokes that code with the SQL statement?

Comment: Hi David, i have updated the question with the whole logic, sorry for not explaining better before.

Comment: So the UI-facing method `BookingTrendRead` is what gets invoked? Whatever is making the HTTP request to that method would need to include the desired value, then. I don't see anything in your client-side code which actually makes that request, though. If the `select` element is part of a form which posts to that action method then you can get the value from the POST data. (Though you do need to give the `select` element a `name` attribute first.) Or use the MVC model binding and have a parameter on that action method. It's really sounding like you would benefit from an intro MVC tutorial.

Comment: i really don't have a clue....i just been asked to complete it and i am struggling...everything works atm...without using selected value from select2 which is what i am trying to implement into the current code.

Comment: Honestly, your first step here is to learn the basics of MVC.  I can tell you that you should add a `name` attribute to your `select` element, something like `name="schoolDestinations"`.  And then add a parameter to the action method, something like: `public ActionResult BookingTrendRead(string[] schoolDestinations)` But these suggestions will only get you so far if you don't understand the fundamentals of the framework you're using. (Not to mention that I don't even know if that's how your requests are set up.)  You're using ASP.NET MVC, so your first step is going to be to learn ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

you need to split out the name of your select from within the sql string:

```
strBuilder.Append("select WEEKNO, YEARNO, SUM(NOOFWEEKS) from BOOKINGTREND where ( SCHOOLCOUNTRY in (" + select2.selectedText + ")) group by weekno, yearno");
```

Comment: And where does `select2.selectedText` come from?

Comment: ok, the full code was not there when I answered, assumed there was a server side control with that name